# How to detect when the cancel button is pressed in SearchBar in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to detect when the cancel button on the `SearchBar` is pressed? I have not found any events for this button and I have not found any information about this.

[image]

Comment: Functionally is not much different that button than selectting the text and deleting it. Have you considered using the text changed event?

Comment: What I need is to do other functions once that button is clicked instead of just deleting the text. That is why I need to detect when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with custom renderer. I make a sample for your reference to change the cancel button icon when you press it.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySearchBar), typeof(MySearchBarRenderer))]
namespace App10.Droid
{
public class MySearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    public MySearchBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var searchView = Control;
            searchView.Iconified = true;
            searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);
            int searchIconId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
            var icon = searchView.FindViewById(searchIconId);

            icon.Click += delegate {
                (icon as ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.star_small); 
            
            };

        }
    }
}
}
```

`search_close_btn` is the id of the imageview of the cancel button in searchbar source code.  You could check the source code with the link below. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwnTp.jpg